Close Associated Token Account (token 2022 program) to get back deposited sol
I have created 2 types of Associated Token Account:
1, Use token program: https://solscan.io/tx/3BC6yNwcaandgzSgFX4YP1nYopPLsa9RyRdqi4bDmKLpWsjiRqMKRaQaoZhgbBQpEsMhcFLoZwobKMVZvrLuUi6C
2, Use token 2022 program:
https://solscan.io/tx/615Q7tW715HBvLHqnvPUXDX5ELFKgRdHQhNLYegWKHrtpgAp1jv6ccbZPnPtE3R5YPJXTxjfmmGMRpdBMMaFKnVE
I can close ATA in #1 with this code below:
import fs from 'fs';
import csv from 'csv-parser';
import { createObjectCsvWriter } from 'csv-writer';
import { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, closeAccount } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { getExplorerLink } from "@solana-developers/helpers";
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl, Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import bs58 from "bs58";

// Initialize connection
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));

// Substitute in your token mint account
const tokenMintAccount = new PublicKey("Bv2ajiWdngTyRFabXCKiwGDJh5SEfJwoRPkkTQ2uf6EE");

// CSV writer for failed transactions
const csvWriter = createObjectCsvWriter({
  path: 'failed_send.csv',
  header: [{ id: 'prvkey', title: 'PrivateKey' }, { id: 'error', title: 'Error' }]
});

// Function to process each private key with retry logic and close token account
async function processPrivateKey(privateKeyBase58) {
  const user = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(privateKeyBase58));
  const recipient = user.publicKey;
  let success = false;
  let delayTime = 1500; // Start with 1.5 seconds delay

  for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= 3; attempt++) {
    try {
      console.log(` Attempt ${attempt} for keypair with public key: ${user.publicKey.toBase58()}`);

      let tokenAccount;

      try {
        // Check if the associated token account exists
        tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
          connection,
          user,
          tokenMintAccount,
          recipient
        );
        console.log(`Token Account: ${tokenAccount.address.toBase58()}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching/creating token account: ${error.message || error}`);
        throw error; // Re-throw the error to retry
      }

      // If token account exists, proceed to close it
      const closeTx = await closeAccount(
        connection,
        user, // payer
        tokenAccount.address, // address of the token account to be closed
        recipient, // destination wallet for SOL
        user // owner of the token account
      );

      const link = getExplorerLink(
        "tx",
        closeTx,
        "mainnet-beta"
      );

      console.log(`✅ Closed token Account: ${link}`);
      success = true;
      break;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error on attempt ${attempt} for private key ${privateKeyBase58}: ${error.message || error}`);

      if (error.message.includes("429 Too Many Requests")) {
        console.log('Hit rate limit, increasing delay...');
      }

      await delay(delayTime); // Wait before retrying
      delayTime *= 2; // Exponentially increase delay time (1.5s, 3s, 6s, etc.)
    }
  }

  if (!success) {
    return { prvkey: privateKeyBase58, error: 'Failed after 3 attempts' };
  }
}

// Function to delay for a specified number of milliseconds
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Read the CSV file and process each private key with a delay and retry logic
(async () => {
  const rows = [];
  const failedKeys = [];

  fs.createReadStream('key.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
      rows.push(row);
    })
    .on('end', async () => {
      console.log('CSV file successfully processed.');

      for (const row of rows) {
        const privateKeyBase58 = row.prvkey;
        const result = await processPrivateKey(privateKeyBase58);
        if (result) {
          failedKeys.push(result);
        }
        await delay(1500); // Wait for 1.5 seconds before processing the next key
      }

      if (failedKeys.length > 0) {
        await csvWriter.writeRecords(failedKeys);
        console.log('Failed private keys have been recorded in failed_tx.csv.');
      }

      console.log('All private keys processed.');
    });
})();

When I try to close ATA in #2 with change token mint account from Bv2ajiWdngTyRFabXCKiwGDJh5SEfJwoRPkkTQ2uf6EE to BorpaZo2RdiYcriLJu2GRefZdgQPmv63nA8jsVVsMV7W, it shows:
TokenAccountNotFoundError

Please help me!

You need to specify the token-2022 program id as a normal positional argument, and not in a new object. Try doing:
      const closeTx = await closeAccount(
        connection,
        user, // payer
        tokenAccount.address, // address of the token account to be closed
        recipient, // destination wallet for SOL
        user, // owner of the token account
        [], // multisig signers
        undefined, // confirm options
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Specify TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID here
      );

Looking at the source code: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/actions/closeAccount.ts#L21
Same for getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount. Try doing:
          tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            user,
            tokenMintAccount,
            recipient,
            false,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
          );

Source cdoe at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/933ae6c0cba427b6ac342b40fa55da436953ab7d/token/js/src/actions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L30

Yeah, thank you so much! <33333

I have edited my code that add token_2022_program_id but it doesn't work:
import fs from 'fs';
import csv from 'csv-parser';
import { createObjectCsvWriter } from 'csv-writer';
import {
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
  closeAccount,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
} from '@solana/spl-token';
import { getExplorerLink } from '@solana-developers/helpers';
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import bs58 from 'bs58';

// Initialize connection
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));

// Substitute in your token mint account
const tokenMintAccount = new PublicKey('BorpaZo2RdiYcriLJu2GRefZdgQPmv63nA8jsVVsMV7');

// CSV writer for failed transactions
const csvWriter = createObjectCsvWriter({
  path: 'failed_send.csv',
  header: [{ id: 'prvkey', title: 'PrivateKey' }, { id: 'error', title: 'Error' }],
});

// Function to process each private key with retry logic and close token account
async function processPrivateKey(privateKeyBase58) {
  const user = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(privateKeyBase58));
  const recipient = user.publicKey;
  let success = false;
  let delayTime = 1500; // Start with 1.5 seconds delay

  for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= 3; attempt++) {
    try {
      console.log(` Attempt ${attempt} for keypair with public key: ${user.publicKey.toBase58()}`);

      let tokenAccount;

      try {
        // Attempt to get the associated token account
        tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
          connection,
          user,
          tokenMintAccount,
          recipient,
          false,
          { programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID } // Specify TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID here
        );
        console.log(`Token Account: ${tokenAccount.address.toBase58()}`);
      } catch (error) {
        // Check if the error is related to the token account not being found
        if (error.name === 'TokenAccountNotFoundError') {
          console.log('Token account not found. Attempting to create a new one...');
          // Attempt to create the token account again, rethrowing any unexpected errors
          tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            user,
            tokenMintAccount,
            recipient,
            false,
            { programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID }
          );
          console.log(`Created new Token Account: ${tokenAccount.address.toBase58()}`);
        } else {
          console.error(`Unexpected error fetching/creating token account: ${error.message || error}`);
          throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it later
        }
      }

      // If token account exists, proceed to close it
      const closeTx = await closeAccount(
        connection,
        user, // payer
        tokenAccount.address, // address of the token account to be closed
        recipient, // destination wallet for SOL
        user, // owner of the token account
        { programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID } // Specify TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID here
      );

      const link = getExplorerLink('tx', closeTx, 'mainnet-beta');
      console.log(`✅ Closed token Account: ${link}`);
      success = true;
      break; // Exit loop on success
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error on attempt ${attempt} for private key ${privateKeyBase58}: ${error.message || error}`);

      if (error.message.includes('429 Too Many Requests')) {
        console.log('Hit rate limit, increasing delay...');
      }

      await delay(delayTime); // Wait before retrying
      delayTime *= 2; // Exponentially increase delay time (1.5s, 3s, 6s, etc.)
    }
  }

  if (!success) {
    return { prvkey: privateKeyBase58, error: 'Failed after 3 attempts' };
  }
}

// Function to delay for a specified number of milliseconds
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Read the CSV file and process each private key with a delay and retry logic
(async () => {
  const rows = [];
  const failedKeys = [];

  fs.createReadStream('key.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
      rows.push(row);
    })
    .on('end', async () => {
      console.log('CSV file successfully processed.');

      for (const row of rows) {
        const privateKeyBase58 = row.prvkey;
        const result = await processPrivateKey(privateKeyBase58);
        if (result) {
          failedKeys.push(result);
        }
        await delay(1500); // Wait for 1.5 seconds before processing the next key
      }

      if (failedKeys.length > 0) {
        await csvWriter.writeRecords(failedKeys);
        console.log('Failed private keys have been recorded in failed_send.csv.');
      }

      console.log('All private keys processed.');
    });
})();

